# Mock the MFMailComposeViewController on iOS simulator. Just need to display the composer

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I just need to display the email composer on my iOS simulator (No need to send the actual mail).

As soon as I am initializing the `MFMailComposeViewController` I am getting alert pop - up saying that email account is not set.

This is what I am doing.

```
MFMailComposeViewController* composeVC = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
```

This line pops up the alert controller.

Answer (score 1):

For simulator email configuration is not available.

Use the below code to send email.

```
- (void)openEmail
{
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mail =
        [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mail setSubject:@"Subject"];
        [mail setMessageBody:@"body message" isHTML:NO];
        [mail setToRecipients:@[@"email1@example.com",@"email2@example.com"]];
        /// if attachment then implement below line
        //[mail addAttachmentData:<#(nonnull NSData *)#> mimeType:<#(nonnull NSString *)#> fileName:<#(nonnull NSString *)#>]
        [self presentViewController:mail animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Please configure your email. Settings->Accounts & Passwords->Add Account");
    }
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(nullable NSError *)error
{
    switch (result) {
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Sent");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to display the email composer only using simulator ? I don't need to use actual email functionality.

Comment: Simulator I don’t think